# How to remember element position in DOM

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I have an element which I need to append into other element, and after some other manipulation I need to put element back to its default position.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Save the object's parent with [`.data()`](http://api.jquery.com/data/) and retrieve it when you move it back.

```
$( '#move' ).data( 'originalParent', $( '#move' ).parent() );  

// moving to new position
$( '#moveToNew' ).click( function() {
    $( '#move' ).appendTo( '#new' );
});

// move element back to where it was
$( '#moveBack' ).click( function() {
    $( '#move' ).appendTo( $( '#move' ).data( 'originalParent' ) );
});
```

Comment: Why do you have to move the `data2` div out first? Just append what you want to be the last element. It doesn't overwrite the existing content.

Answer (score 0):

you should use $.data in  jQuery

or you can clone the object and then used the cloned one to revert